# Maui Blazor Button Click With Navigation

Tags: navigation, blazor, maui

I have a page with a button that calls an asynchronous webapi and then navigates to another page. However, although the code runs without errors it does not go to the new page. Instead the current page just reappears.

My code:

```
C#
private async void Method()
{
 SendVerificationCodeResponse response = await Post<SendVerificationCodeResponse>(url,
  new SendVerificationCodeParam { Number = number });

 if (response.IsSuccess)
 {
  navManager.NavigateTo($"/verify-code?from=signin&number={number}", true);
 }
}

private async Task<ResponseType> Post<ResponseType>(string url, object param)
{
    ResponseType returnResponse = default;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var serializedStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(serializedStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string contentStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            returnResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseType>(contentStr);
        }
    }
    return returnResponse;
}

Razor
<button @onclick="Method">Button Description</button>
```

I imagine the button onclick is meant to perform page changes rather than navigation?? I don't know, but I know the page is correct and the code is not breaking.

EDIT:
I've created a new boilerplate project and added my basic code to it. I've found that the page gets navigated too but then the original page gets displayed. I'm hoping this helps to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Did this route `$"/verify-code?from=signin&number={number}"` right in your navigation?

Comment: It is correct and working.  I get expected behaviour if I put everything in a form and perform a submit. I just didn’t want to have to do that when I don’t think I should have too

Answer (score 0):

Taking the code you're provided, we can create the following Minimal Reproducible Example.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" @onclick="DoAsync">Click me</button>

@code{
    private async void DoAsync()
    {
        //Fake an async call
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }
}
```

This works as it should: waits 3 seconds and then navigates.

While this pattern:

```cs
    private async void DoAsync()
```

is a **NoNo** for UI event handlers. It should be:

```cs
private async Task DoAsync()
```

It's not the root cause in this case.  That's whatever you're doing in:

````cs
   //perform async web call.
   //code
```.
````

Comment: I'll add the web call. Thanks for looking

Comment: Based on your code `response.IsSuccess` must be `false`.  Put in a `Console.Writeline` to check it.

Comment: I can confirm that has been checked

Comment: [Polite] I don't think I can help any further.  I'm puzzled by the generics, specifying the response type in the method, but you will have your reasons.

Comment: I've had to resort to performing page form posts and then navigating on submit. It works. but I'm sure it can't be right. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem. I had the button click inside a form tag on my page and the button type was not set so it defaulted to submit. Everytime it was clicked it tried posting and performing my async web call followed by page navigation. It then became confused and I got intermittent results.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" @onclick="DoAsync" type="button">Click me</button>
```